# How do I call a specific web service method with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, database, wsdl

How do I call a specific WSDL method via ajax.. I have the following service:

http://newsite.wrapcompliance.org/FactoriesWS.wsdl

and I'm trying to call the method `factCountByCountryID()`, which returns an integer when given a 3 character string. Code so far is as follows:

```
<h3>jQuery Test</h3>

<script type="text/javascript">

function callService()
{
$.ajax
({
    url: "http://newsite.wrapcompliance.org/FactoriesWS.wsdl",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data: {"countryCd":"BGD"},
    success: processData,
    error: onError
});

return false;
}

function processData(xml)
{
    alert(xml);
}

function onError(request, status, error)
{
alert("It didn't work!!!");
}

</script>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="button" value="Do it now!!" onclick="callService(); return false"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried `http://newsite.wrapcompliance.org/FactoriesWS.wsdl/factCountByCountryID`

Comment: Yes, the .ajax function went to the error case. The error was "Not Found"

Comment: The people that were so quick to label this question as "duplicate" did not bother to notice that the question they think this duplicates was actually about linking to the jQuery library and other than "jQuery" has little to do with the question being asked here.

Comment: OP did not state what the error was. His code has no indication that it's actually loading the jQuery library. So it makes sense people thought his error is because of this. If it's not, then OP, please state what your exact error is and indicate that you're using jQuery properly, and I'll be happy to add my reopen vote.

Comment: If he hasn't actually loaded the jQuery library then how on Earth would the error-calling function even work?  It would have failed at "$.ajax" and returned a completely different error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery.soap](https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap/blob/master/README.md) plugin which will handle the SOAP part for you. You need to configure it first and than you can use:

```
$.soap({
    method: 'factCountByCountryID',
    params: {
        countryCd: 'BGD',
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // do stuff with data
    }
});
```

Comment: this looks interesting. Do I need to include any additional .js files for this to work? I read the link you provided and I didn't see one.

Comment: Yes you need. Plugin's website and download is here: http://plugins.jquery.com/soap/

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have the wrong address! WSDL only describes a service, it's not the service implementation itself. If you do like this, you will point your reqest on a file, nothing more. Altough there's a service description in wsdl: 
"http://apollov-dev.worlddata.com:8080/WrapSystem/services/FactoriesWS"

In addtion, you have to send a valid SOAP message, what will be consumed on the server side. [described in your WSDL]

Some kind of tutorial:
http://openlandscape.net/2009/09/25/call-soap-xm-web-services-with-jquery-ajax/