# PHP SoapClient wsdl after login page

Tags: php, wsdl, soap-client

I need to load a wsdl file through php SoapClient class, however to access the url of the file it is necessary to be previously authenticated.

To better exemplify my problem I will describe how I can open the wsdl file through the browser:

When accessing https:/server/some.wsdl, an invalid certificate alert is displayed by the browser and after skipping this alert I am redirected to https://server/login.html, after informing the user and password it is finally redirected to https://server/some.wsdl.

Comment: Can you modify the server itself? This sounds like an issue with that server.

Comment: does it have to be SOAP, you could use curl and have it follow the redirect and ignore authentication (i think). This page might be some use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120586/soap-request-in-php-with-curl

Comment: I can not change the server configuration and need to use SOAP to consume Webservice.

Comment: Here's a previous question of mine that might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527345/how-do-i-call-a-specific-web-service-method-with-ajax